# Defining specific compiler flag for armv7 compilation in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

I've encountered an issue when compiling my Release builds for armv7 architectures. This is due to me using C++17 with iOS 10. The error itself looks like:

```
cpprest/include/pplx/pplxtasks.h:586:63: error: aligned allocation function of type 'void *(std::size_t, std::align_val_t)' is only available on iOS 11 or newer [-Waligned-allocation-unavailable]
        _TaskCollection_t::_RunTask(&_TaskProcThunk::_Bridge, new _TaskProcThunk(_Func), _InliningMode);
```

I came across this posting

https://forum.juce.com/t/error-building-ios-for-device-in-release-mode/28595/8

Where the suggestion is to use `-fno-aligned-allocation` for older hardware.

I set this globally and it does indeed seem to work during the compilation.

I was trying to set the compiler flag based on architecture. This used to be feasible. Now, it looks like you can set the SDK version (limited), but not the architecture.

Is this possible to do anymore? Or alternatively is there a way I can do some form of `pragma` or similar and put some compiler directives to set this within the header files? I know that is a bit gross sounding, but I ideally want to keep iOS 10 as a deployment target.

[image]

Comment: I have found if one edits the pbxproj directly one can modify the architecture. I've notified Apple on this.